# A collision function is not allowing my missile to move

Tags: javascript

http://pastebin.com/29CTCneE

Inside the `drawMissile()` function I make it so it moves the missile's y position 5 pixels each frame! But there is also another function being called: `missileCollision()`

Inside the `missileCollision()` function it checks if it is touching the bowl, if it is, then it will give you a point and reset the position! But if the missile misses the bowl and goes to the bottom of the screen, then you lose a life!

Here is the problem, when it calls the "missileCollision()" function, it won't move down 5 pixels! I tried taking out the "missileCollision()" function, it worked as it should! Why does calling the "missileCollision()" function stops my missile from moving?

I had also tried removing the "missileCollision()" function entirely and just cut and pasted the code into the "drawMissile" function but that didn't work :(

*-Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't check all the code but this line (86) looks bad:

```
if (missileY = playerY-missileYThick ..
```

You're doing an assignment here. Use `===` (instead of `=`) to compare two variables of the same type.

Comment: So that means that it was constantly setting the value to 0! Thanks for the help  I'll be sure to keep this in mind!